# Interchanging string value position

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

Is it possible to interchange a number of values of string position?

To explain it clearly here:

Is it possible for `103414823111` to be altered to something like this `823111103414`.

To make it detailed:

I want to `103414` be placed after `823111` instead of having it before.

The cutting of that certain data is done now my problem is moving it to front.

Here's my code for cutting it.

```
[Time] = SUBSTRING('351856040667941,RA1;0500A1437.8305N12057.1792E000.0087.600.800051034148231114CEA2420018A140000000', 65, 6),
[Date] = SUBSTRING('351856040667941,RA1;0500A1437.8305N12057.1792E000.0087.600.800051034148231114CEA2420018A140000000', 72, 6),
```

I need help badly guys. Thanks.

Comment: is `823111` the time or the date

Comment: Date Sir. The 103414  is the Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
declare @a varchar (500)='103414823111'
select right(@a,6)+left(@a,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT (RIGHT([Date],6), (LEFT ([Time], 6))
```

OR

```
SELECT CONCAT ([Date],[Time])
```